# Django autoconversion of strings to datetimes

Tags: python, django, sqlite, datetime

Testing with SQLite, Django will converts strings to datetimes automatically when saving to the database, but discard updates from invalid strings without erroring.  Is this behavior consistent across all Django database backends?  Where is this documented?  Also, how do I determine if a datetime in string form that I have received from an external source (not a Django form) will be valid with Django's database?

Looking through the code, `django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime` appears to be what Django uses in it's SQLite database backend.  The other database backends appear to not use this, nor does this interact with the `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` used by Django forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#section_2_2

Thus this behavior is very different from PostgreSQL and mysql both of which happen to have separate data types for date, time and datetimes.

So the answer to "*Is this behavior consistent across all Django database backends?*" is no

"*Where is this documented?*" refer above link

"*Also, how do I determine if a datetime in string form that I have received from an external source (not a Django form) will be valid with Django's database?*" It depends. If you have trouble with specific dates and times received from external sources, I would suggest a separate question on it.